# pip install --user pyqt5 how to set the path of python?

Tags: python-3.8

i have been trying to install pyqt5 using terminal of Pycharm,
but i faced this warning:

```
 WARNING: The scripts pylupdate5.exe, pyrcc5.exe and pyuic5.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roa
ming\Python\Python39\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-loca
tion.
```

i can't remove this python folder inside this path.
so how to install pyqt5 inside the correct path?

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
pip install pyqt5-tools
```

Comment: Even i try this i'll get same warning